# Set a structure with -

Tags: texworks, structure

What's a command to structure text with -
E.g.

-first part here

-second part here

So i can structure parts of text with that.
Guess it is scientifically wrong to use -

Comment: You mean a [list](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists)?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer or *at least* comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[--] first part here 
    \item[--]second part here
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```